# Using Multiple DataSources Configuration class in Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven

Our application need to deal with multiple databases. We tried to configure multiple data sources through Hibernate configuration and added two configurations one for database 1 and second for database 2. This configuration fails with following Exception

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactory1,sessionFactory2
Nov 29, 2019 5:08:11 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactory1,sessionFactory2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
```

This is my Configuration class :

```
package com.pack1.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

import com.pack1.routing.MyRoutingDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.pack1")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement

// Load to Environment
@PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:ds/datasource-cfg.properties")})

public class ApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{


    // The Environment class serves as the property holder
    // and stores all the properties loaded by the @PropertySource
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    // Returns Routing DataSource (MyRoutingDataSource)
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource(DataSource dataSource1, DataSource dataSource2) {

        System.out.println("## Create DataSource from dataSource1 & dataSource2");

        MyRoutingDataSource dataSource = new MyRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dsMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        dsMap.put("PUBLISHER_DS", dataSource1);
        dsMap.put("ADVERTISER_DS", dataSource2);

        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(dsMap);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    public DataSource getDataSource1() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // See: datasouce-cfg.properties
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver1"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url1"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("ds.username1"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password1"));

        System.out.println("## getDataSource1: " + dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties1() 
    {
        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect1", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect1"));
        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql1", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql1"));

        return props;
    }

 // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty1(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory1() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException{

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource1());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.packagesToScan1"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties1());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager1(SessionFactory sessionFactory1) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory 
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory1);

        return txManager;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    public DataSource getDataSource2() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // See: datasouce-cfg.properties
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver2"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url2"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("ds.username2"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password2"));

        System.out.println("## getDataSource2: " + dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties2() 
    {
        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect2", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect2"));
        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql2", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql2"));

        return props;
    }

 // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty2(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException{

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory1 = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory1.setDataSource(getDataSource2());
        sessionFactory1.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.packagesToScan2"));
        sessionFactory1.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties2());

        return sessionFactory1;
    }


    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManage2(SessionFactory sessionFactory1) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory 
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory1);

        return txManager;
    }

}
```

I am new to using multiple Datasource in Spring MVC. Please help me Coding in Hibernate Configuration class .

Comment: Check your logs. But my guess, you have 3 datasources, non marked as `@Primary`. Mark your routing datasource as `@Primary`.

Comment: Hello Brother,I have only 2 dataSources ,where i should keep @Primary annotation

Comment: No you have 3. 2 you are delegating 2 and additionally the routing one, effectifly, for the application, 3 datasources. As already stated in m y comment mark the routing one `MyRoutingDataSource` as primary.

Comment: done bro its coming,thank you for support and help ,please give me pionts